# How to add 'odd' and 'even' classes to divs (Jquery)?

Tags: jquery, html, class

How to add 'odd' and 'even' classes to divs using Jquery?
I have this html

```
<div class="carousel" >
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

and I need to add 'odd' and 'even' classes to the 'div.item' to get this

```
<div class="carousel" >
   <div class="item odd"></div>
   <div class="item even"></div>
   <div class="item odd"></div>
   <div class="item even"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`:odd`](https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) and [`:even`](https://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) selector

```
 $('.carousel item:odd').addClass('odd');
 $('.carousel item:even').addClass('even');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the css3 :nth-child

```js
$('.carousel .item:nth-child(even)').addClass('even');
$('.carousel .item:nth-child(odd)').addClass('odd');
```

```css
.odd {
  color: red;
}
.even {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

or jQuery [odd](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/)/[even](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) selectors - you need to swap the class & selector since in jQuery the index starts with 0

```js
$('.carousel .item:nth-child(even)').addClass('even');
$('.carousel .item:nth-child(odd)').addClass('odd');
```

```css
.odd {
  color: red;
}
.even {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:odd` and `:even` pseudo-selectors.

```
$('.item:odd').addClass('odd');
$('.item:even').addClass('even');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/tdhbh9un/

`:odd`:

> Selects odd elements, zero-indexed.

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/

`:even`:

> Selects even elements, zero-indexed

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/even-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('.carousel item:odd').addClass('odd');

 $('.carousel item:even').addClass('even');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning **odd** class to **even** and **even** class to **odd** will produce the required result

That is:

```
 $(".carousel div:even").addClass( "odd" );
```

AND

```
  $(".carousel div:odd").addClass( "even" );
```

Will produce the required result.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Create a polyline using Geolocation and Google Maps API</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".carousel div:even").addClass( "odd" );
        $(".carousel div:odd").addClass( "even" ); 
        alert($(".carousel").html());
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="carousel" >
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```