# How to append custom option values using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help me with this?
Note: Project is a dynamic Webflow website, so the entries get generated as described below, I can only change class names

Let's say I have multiple items I want to append to a select field

```
<div class="item-category">Kitchen</div>
<div class="actual-item">Spoon</div>
<div class="item-category">Living room</div>
<div class="actual-item">Sofa</div>
<div class="item-category">Kitchen</div>
<div class="actual-item">Plate</div>
```

I'm able to append items using `actual-item` class

```
$('.actual-item').each(function(){
var s=$(this).text();
$('.item-select-field').append('<option value="'+s+'">'+s+'</option>');
})
```

But I want to have `option value` equal to corresponding `item-category` (so I could filter items out later).
Is there any way to do this?
I've thought of changing the `item-category` class to `actual-item` and then using only even elements as `option-value` but I don't know to do this.

Comment: `.prev()`. Or of you can change HTML, put value as `data-item-category="Kitchen">Plate</div>`

Comment: Build your html with the data you need:  `<div class="item" data-category="living room">Sofa</div><div class="item" data-category="living room">TV</div>` *or* group your data hierarchically - `<div class="category">Kitchen<div>Spoon</div><div>Fork</div></div>` (or use nested `ul`/`li`)

Comment: If your `option value=` matches the category, then the end result will be a number of `option`s with the same `value=` - which really won't help you in the long run.  Use `data-` attributes liberally.

Comment: @freedomn-m I can't add `data-category` because it's a dynamic Webflow website, entries get generated as in the   description, I might be able to nest `actual-item` in the `item-category` but I still don't know where to go from there

Comment: Always useful to add in the question that your source (html) is from a third-party that you can't change.  99% of the time it's better to change the source rather than try to manipulate it post-render.  But if you can't, you can't.  Or at least state how much you *can* change as it looks like you can change classes?  I have no idea what you mean by "a dynamic webflow website"

Comment: "*I've thought of changing the item-category class to actual-item and then using only even elements*" - [here's how to select only odd/even items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526230/how-to-add-odd-and-even-classes-to-divs-jquery), though updating your markup to more clearly identify the relationships seems safer, if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your HTML will always be category followed by item, you can find the items then use `.prev()` to get the previous `div` which contains the category:

```
var category = $(this).prev().text()
```

As the requirement is "*so I could filter items out later*" - you don't want to set the `value=` to category otherwise you get multiple options with the same value, so you don't know which one was selected

```
<option value="Kitchen">Spoon</option>
<option value="Kitchen">Plate</option>
```

instead, you can add a data- attribute to the `<option>`

```
<option data-category="Kitchen">Spoon</option>
<option data-category="Kitchen">Plate</option>
```

then you can use this to filter the options later, eg:

```
$(".item-select-field :not([data-category='Kitchen'])").hide()
```

Giving:

```js
$('.actual-item').each(function() {
  var val = $(this).text();
  var cat = $(this).prev().text();
  $('.item-select-field').append('<option value="' + val + '" data-category="' + cat + '">' + cat + ":" + val + '</option>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-category">Kitchen</div>
<div class="actual-item">Spoon</div>
<div class="item-category">Living room</div>
<div class="actual-item">Sofa</div>
<div class="item-category">Kitchen</div>
<div class="actual-item">Plate</div>

<select class='item-select-field'>
</select>
```

---

You could equally get each category and use `.next()` to get the item for that category, which ever makes the most sense to you.

```js
$('.item-category').each(function() {
  var cat = $(this).text();
  var val = $(this).next().text();
  $('.item-select-field').append('<option value="' + val + '" data-category="' + cat + '">' + cat + ":" + val + '</option>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-category">Kitchen</div>
<div class="actual-item">Spoon</div>
<div class="item-category">Living room</div>
<div class="actual-item">Sofa</div>
<div class="item-category">Kitchen</div>
<div class="actual-item">Plate</div>

<select class='item-select-field'>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
This is what I couldn't figure out
`var category = $(this).prev().text()`

Comment: on a side note, is it possible to use something else instead of value in the code below? Filtering works great with `this.value`, but it doesn't work if I switch it with `this.data-category` for example.

`$(function() {
    $('#select-item').on('change', function() {
        var  itemVal= this.value;
        $('#select-secondItem option').hide().filter(function() {
            return this.value.indexOf(itemVal) === 0;
        })
        .show();
    })
    .change();
});`

Comment: Change `this.value.indexOf(itemVal) === 0` to `$(this).data("category") === itemVal`

Comment: I'm getting reference error for `itemVal=this.data-category` 
I've tried with `itemVal=this.data("category")` but didn't work

Comment: Don't mix up `=` with `==`

Comment: No code error with `var  itemVal=$(this).data("category");` but filtering doesn't work

Comment: You should be comparing `itemVal` with `.data("category")` - not setting it.  Your code was `$('#select-secondItem option').hide().filter(function() { return this.value.indexOf(itemVal) === 0;  })` but should/could be `$('#select-secondItem option').hide().filter(function() {  return $(this).data("category") === itemVal; })` - why are you changing `var itemVal =`?

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question (can link to it from here) where you'll be able to provide a complete code snippet that's well formatted.  Answer comments aren't the best place for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67534135/modify-filter-function-for-select-options-in-jquery

Comment: See, makes much more sense in your new question.  I assumed you were matching category *value* to item data-category, but there's no need to and you can match data- to data-.

Comment: thanks a lot man, you really helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based off [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2162574/12415287).

Use this format: `new Option("option text", "value");`

```js
$('.actual-item').each(function(){
    var s = $(this).text();
    var o = new Option(s, s);
    
    $(".item-select").append(o);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-category">Kitchen</div>
<div class="actual-item">Spoon</div>
<div class="item-category">Living room</div>
<div class="actual-item">Sofa</div>
<div class="item-category">Kitchen</div>
<div class="actual-item">Plate</div>

<select class="item-select">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly I believe this is the effect you're trying to achieve.

I've gathered all of the items and their parent categories and used the [optgroup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) element to group them inside of the select.

I've also modified your HTML slightly so the relationship between category and item is more obvious inside the markup.

```js
$('.actual-item').each(function(){
  const option = $(this).text();
  const optgroup = $(this).parent().find('.category-title').text();
  
  if ($(`[label="${optgroup}"]`).length) {
    $(`[label="${optgroup}"]`).append(`<option value="${option}">${option}</option>`);
  } else {
    $('.item-select-field').append(`
      <optgroup label="${optgroup}">
        <option value="${option}">${option}</option>
      </optgroup
    `);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item-category">
  <span class="category-title">Kitchen</span>
  <div class="actual-item">Spoon</div>
  <div class="actual-item">Knife</div>
  <div class="actual-item">Fork</div>
</div>

<div class="item-category">
  <span class="category-title">Living room</span>
  <div class="actual-item">Sofa</div>
</div>

<div class="item-category">
  <span class="category-title">Kitchen</span>
  <div class="actual-item">Plate</div>
</div>

<label for="item-select">Choose an item:</label>
<select id="item-select" class="item-select-field"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

hard way

```js
const zip = (...arr) => {
   const zipped = [];
   arr.forEach((element, ind) => {
      element.forEach((el, index) => {
         if(!zipped[index]){
            zipped[index] = [];
         };
         if(!zipped[index][ind]){
            zipped[index][ind] = [];
         }
         zipped[index][ind] = el || '';
      })
   });
   return zipped;
};

const combined = zip($('.actual-item').toArray(), $('.item-category').toArray())

$(combined).each(function(){
  console.log({'value': $(this[0]).text(), 'category': $(this[1]).text()})
})
```

```
{value: "Spoon", category: "Kitchen"}
{value: "Sofa", category: "Living room"}
{value: "Plate", category: "Kitchen"}
```

PS thanks to this [info](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript-equivalent-of-python-s-zip-function)